# Displaying Previous Week Date Interval in MS Report Builder

Tags: reportbuilder

I'm trying to display a date Range in Report Builder for "last week". For example, today is 8/10. So I need to show something like: **"August 02, 2020 to August 08, 2020"**

If I use the following expression as part of an SQL Query it works just fine. But, when I attempt to use this as an Expression in a Textbox in Report Builder, I get an error.

```
=format(DateAdd("week",-1,DateAdd("week",DateDiff("week",0,getdate()),0)), "MMMM dd, yyyy")
```

This throws an Error when I click Run, that says:

> The Value expression for the textrun ‘Textbox14.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ contains an error: [BC30451] 'getdate' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

For the "week" keyword, I've tried double/single quoting it, no quotes, using just "w" with and without quotes/single-quotes. If "week" or "w" is not quoted, the error says *'week' is not declared...*

However, if I run the following Select Query, I get the correct dates:

```
SELECT format(DateAdd(week,-1,DateAdd(week,DateDiff(week,0,getdate()),0)) - 1, 'MMMM dd, yyyy')
, format(DateAdd(week,-1,DateAdd(week,DateDiff(week,0,getdate()),0)) + 5, 'MMMM dd, yyyy')
```

Using a "-1" because the result of the first DateAdd() returns the previous Monday. Then the 2nd part is "+5" to get me the previous Saturday's date.

Lastly, I tried replacing "GetDate()" with "Now()". When I do this, the report will run. But, the textbox just shows **"#Error"**.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Got some assistance from a MS forum. The below expressions work in Report Builder Text Boxes.

**First Day of previous week (Sunday)**

```
=format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -7,DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 1-Weekday(today),Today)),"MMMM dd, yyyy")
```

**Last Day of previous week (Saturday)**

```
=format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -1,DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 1-Weekday(today),Today)),"MMMM dd, yyyy")
```

-Matt